# How to cover the line throw new AuraHandledException in the last method on the AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl to the test class?

Tags: apex, aura, aura-handler

How to cover the line if (minhaSolicitacao == null) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('Registro não encontrado'); in the last method on the AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl to the test class?
Observation: The line it's marked by *

```
@isTest
public class AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoTest {

     @isTest static void getDetalhesSolicitacao(){

         User usuario = new User(Username = 'Joãoo@joao.teste', LastName = 'Constantino' ,Email = 'joao@joao.teste', Alias = 'GEST', CommunityNickname = 'COM_GESTOR', TimeZoneSidKey = 'Pacific/Kiritimati', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name IN ('Gestor') limit 1].Id, LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', FuncionalColaborador__c = 'FUNCIONAL_GESSTOR', Title = 'GESTOR', Department = 'GESTOR_TESTE'); 

        insert usuario;



        Case idSolicitar = new Case();
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Vigencia_Mudanca__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Novo_Valor_Aluguel__c=decimal.valueOf(29);
        idSolicitar.Inicio_Beneficio__c=date.parse('20/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.DataAbertura__c=date.parse('21/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Numero_Solicitacao__c='0393';
        idSolicitar.OwnerId= usuario.id;
        idSolicitar.Status='pendente';
        idSolicitar.Valor_Aluguel__c=decimal.valueOf(39);
        idSolicitar.Previsao_Encerramento__c=date.parse('20/08/2019');
        idSolicitar.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeMemory.getRecType('Case', 'Ajuda_Residencia_Alteracao_Contrato');
        insert idSolicitar;


        Test.startTest();

        System.runAs(usuario){
        try{   
        Case minhaSolicitacao = AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl.getDetalhesSolicitacao();
        } catch(AuraHandledException e){   
        }
        }

        try{
            Case minhaSolicitacao = AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl.getDetalhesSolicitacao();

        }catch(AuraHandledException e ){

        }
    }


    @isTest static void getAnexos(){


        User usuario = new User(Username = 'Joãoo@joao.teste', LastName = 'Constantino' ,Email = 'joao@joao.teste', Alias = 'GEST', CommunityNickname = 'COM_GESTOR', TimeZoneSidKey = 'Pacific/Kiritimati', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name IN ('Gestor') limit 1].Id, LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', FuncionalColaborador__c = 'FUNCIONAL_GESSTOR', Title = 'GESTOR', Department = 'GESTOR_TESTE');
        insert usuario;

            //Case mimhaSolicitacao = new Case();


         //Attachment  a = [SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, Body, Description, ContentType, BodyLength, LastModifiedDate, OwnerId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId =: mimhaSolicitacao.id];
         //insert a;
         //insert b;

        Case idSolicitar = new Case();
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Vigencia_Mudanca__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Novo_Valor_Aluguel__c=decimal.valueOf(029);
        //idSolicitar.Tipo_Solicitacao__c='';
        idSolicitar.Inicio_Beneficio__c=date.parse('20/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.DataAbertura__c=date.parse('21/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('21/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Numero_Solicitacao__c='0393';
        idSolicitar.OwnerId= usuario.Id;
        idSolicitar.Status='pendente';
        idSolicitar.Previsao_Encerramento__c=date.parse('20/08/2019');
        idSolicitar.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeMemory.getRecType('Case', 'Ajuda_Residencia_Alteracao_Contrato');
        insert idSolicitar;

       Attachment  Solicitar = new Attachment(ParentId = idSolicitar.Id, Body = Blob.valueOf('test'), Name= String.valueOf('test.txt'), Description = idSolicitar.Description, OwnerId= idSolicitar.OwnerId);

        insert Solicitar;


        Test.startTest();

        System.runAs(usuario){
        try{
            List<Attachment> anexos = AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl.getAnexos();  
        }catch(AuraHandledException e){
            System.assert(true);

        }
        }

        try{
         List<Attachment> anexos = AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl.getAnexos();  
        }catch(AuraHandledException e){
            System.assert(true);
        }



        Test.stopTest();
    }

        //variaveis do testsetMock
    private static final String return1 = '{"chave_produto":"0008","dados":{"codigo_retorno":"01","descricao_retorno":"PROCESSADO OK","id_solicitacao":"123124","sla":"3"}}';
    private static final String return2 = '{"chave_produto":"0008","dados":{"codigo_retorno":"0","descricao_retorno":"PROCESSADO OK","id_solicitacao":"123124","sla":"3"}}';
    private static final String return3 = '{"chave_produto":"0008","dados":{"codigo_retorno":"05","descricao_retorno":"PROCESSADO OK","id_solicitacao":"123124","sla":"3"}}';

    @isTest static void cancelarSolicitacao1(){

        User usuario = new User(Username = 'Joãoo@joao.teste', LastName = 'Constantino' ,Email = 'joao@joao.teste', Alias = 'GEST', CommunityNickname = 'COM_GESTOR', TimeZoneSidKey = 'Pacific/Kiritimati', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name IN ('Gestor') limit 1].Id, LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', FuncionalColaborador__c = 'FUNCIONAL_GESSTOR', Title = 'GESTOR', Department = 'GESTOR_TESTE');


       insert usuario;


        Case idSolicitar = new Case();
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Vigencia_Mudanca__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Novo_Valor_Aluguel__c=decimal.valueOf(029);
        //idSolicitar.Tipo_Solicitacao__c='';
        idSolicitar.Inicio_Beneficio__c=date.parse('20/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.DataAbertura__c=date.parse('21/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Numero_Solicitacao__c = null;
        idSolicitar.OwnerId= usuario.id;
        idSolicitar.Status='pendente';
        idSolicitar.Previsao_Encerramento__c=date.parse('20/08/2019');
        idSolicitar.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeMemory.getRecType('Case', 'Ajuda_Residencia_Alteracao_Contrato');
        insert idSolicitar;


        Acao_Integracao__c acaoIntegracao;


        acaoIntegracao = new Acao_Integracao__c();
        acaoIntegracao.Name = 'PeopleSoft_0283';
        acaoIntegracao.CodigoServico__c = '0000';
        acaoIntegracao.Modulo__c = 'AlterContrato';
        acaoIntegracao.Timeout__c = 60000;
        acaoIntegracao.Endpoint__c = 'www.google.com.br';
        acaoIntegracao.ServicoNome__c = 'Alteração Contrato';
        insert acaoIntegracao;

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AuxilioResidDetalAlterMock(return3));

        Test.startTest();
        System.runAs(usuario){    
        try{       
            **strong text**AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl.cancelarSolicitacao('');
        }catch(AuraHandledException e){
            System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Script-thrown exception')); 

            }

        }

        Test.stopTest();
    }    

    @isTest static void cancelarSolicitacao2(){

        User usuario = new User(Username = 'Joãoo@joao.teste', LastName = 'Constantino' ,Email = 'joao@joao.teste', Alias = 'GEST', CommunityNickname = 'COM_GESTOR', TimeZoneSidKey = 'Pacific/Kiritimati', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name IN ('Gestor') limit 1].Id, LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', FuncionalColaborador__c = 'FUNCIONAL_GESSTOR', Title = 'GESTOR', Department = 'GESTOR_TESTE');


        insert usuario;

        Case idSolicitar = new Case();
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Vigencia_Mudanca__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Novo_Valor_Aluguel__c=decimal.valueOf(029);
        //idSolicitar.Tipo_Solicitacao__c='';
        idSolicitar.Inicio_Beneficio__c=date.parse('20/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.DataAbertura__c=date.parse('21/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Numero_Solicitacao__c='128';
        idSolicitar.OwnerId= usuario.id;
        idSolicitar.Status='pendente';
        idSolicitar.Previsao_Encerramento__c=date.parse('20/08/2019');
        idSolicitar.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeMemory.getRecType('Case', 'Ajuda_Residencia_Alteracao_Contrato');
        insert idSolicitar;



        Acao_Integracao__c acaoIntegracao;


        acaoIntegracao = new Acao_Integracao__c();
        acaoIntegracao.Name = 'PeopleSoft_0283';
        acaoIntegracao.CodigoServico__c = '0000';
        acaoIntegracao.Modulo__c = 'AlterContrato';
        acaoIntegracao.Timeout__c = 60000;
        acaoIntegracao.Endpoint__c = 'www.google.com.br';
        acaoIntegracao.ServicoNome__c = 'Alteração Contrato';
        insert acaoIntegracao;



        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AuxilioResidDetalAlterMock(return1));


         Test.startTest();

        System.runAs(usuario){
        try{
            AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl.cancelarSolicitacao(idSolicitar.Numero_Solicitacao__c); 

        }catch(AuraHandledException e){
            System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Script-thrown exception')); 

            }
        }
        try{
            AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl.cancelarSolicitacao(idSolicitar.Numero_Solicitacao__c); 
        }catch(AuraHandledException e){
               System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Script-thrown exception'));
        }

        Test.stopTest();
    }

     @isTest static void cancelarSolicitacao3(){

        User usuario = new User(Username = 'Joãoo@joao.teste', LastName = 'Constantino' ,Email = 'joao@joao.teste', Alias = 'GEST', CommunityNickname = 'COM_GESTOR', TimeZoneSidKey = 'Pacific/Kiritimati', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name IN ('Gestor') limit 1].Id, LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', FuncionalColaborador__c = 'FUNCIONAL_GESSTOR', Title = 'GESTOR', Department = 'GESTOR_TESTE');


        insert usuario;

        Case idSolicitar = new Case();
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Vigencia_Mudanca__c=date.parse('20/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Nova_Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('20/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Novo_Valor_Aluguel__c=decimal.valueOf(029);
        //idSolicitar.Tipo_Solicitacao__c='';
        idSolicitar.Inicio_Beneficio__c=date.parse('20/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.DataAbertura__c=date.parse('21/08/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Inicio_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2017');
        idSolicitar.Data_Termino_Contrato__c=date.parse('05/07/2019');
        idSolicitar.Numero_Solicitacao__c='123';
        idSolicitar.OwnerId= usuario.id;
        idSolicitar.Status='pendente';
        idSolicitar.Previsao_Encerramento__c=date.parse('20/08/2019');
        idSolicitar.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeMemory.getRecType('Case', 'Ajuda_Residencia_Alteracao_Contrato');
        insert idSolicitar;



        Acao_Integracao__c acaoIntegracao;


        acaoIntegracao = new Acao_Integracao__c();
        acaoIntegracao.Name = 'PeopleSoft_0283';
        acaoIntegracao.CodigoServico__c = '0000';
        acaoIntegracao.Modulo__c = 'AlterContrato';
        acaoIntegracao.Timeout__c = 60000;
        acaoIntegracao.Endpoint__c = 'www.google.com.br';
        acaoIntegracao.ServicoNome__c = 'Alteração Contrato';
        insert acaoIntegracao;



        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AuxilioResidDetalAlterMock(return2));


         Test.startTest();

        System.runAs(usuario){
        try{
            AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl.cancelarSolicitacao(idSolicitar.Numero_Solicitacao__c); 
        }catch(AuraHandledException e){
            System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Script-thrown exception')); 

            }
        }

        Test.stopTest();
}
```

---

```
public class AuxilioResidDetalhesAlterContratoCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Case getDetalhesSolicitacao() {

        Id RecTypeId = RecordTypeMemory.getRecType('Case', 'Ajuda_Residencia_Alteracao_Contrato');
        Case minhaSolicitacao = new Case();
        try {
            minhaSolicitacao = [SELECT Id, Nova_Data_Inicio_Contrato__c, Data_Vigencia_Mudanca__c, Nova_Data_Termino_Contrato__c, Novo_Valor_Aluguel__c, Tipo_Solicitacao__c, Inicio_Beneficio__c, DataAbertura__c, Data_Inicio_Contrato__c, Data_Termino_Contrato__c, Numero_Solicitacao__c, OwnerId, Status, Valor_Aluguel__c, Previsao_Encerramento__c FROM Case WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND RecordTypeId = :RecTypeId limit 1];
            if (minhaSolicitacao == null) {
                System.debug('Retornou nulo no método getInscricaoAdesao()');
            } else {
                System.debug('Registro encontrado no método getInscricaoAdesao()');
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Ocorreu um erro ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return minhaSolicitacao;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Attachment> getAnexos() {
        Id RecTypeId = RecordTypeMemory.getRecType('Case', 'Ajuda_Residencia_Alteracao_Contrato');
        list<Attachment> anexos = new list<Attachment>();
        Case minhaSolicitacao = new Case();
        try {
            minhaSolicitacao = [SELECT Id, Nova_Data_Inicio_Contrato__c, Data_Vigencia_Mudanca__c, Nova_Data_Termino_Contrato__c, Novo_Valor_Aluguel__c, Tipo_Solicitacao__c, Inicio_Beneficio__c, DataAbertura__c, Data_Inicio_Contrato__c, Data_Termino_Contrato__c, Numero_Solicitacao__c, OwnerId, Status, Valor_Aluguel__c, Previsao_Encerramento__c FROM Case WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND RecordTypeId = :RecTypeId limit 1];
            anexos = [SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, Body, Description, ContentType, BodyLength, LastModifiedDate, OwnerId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :minhaSolicitacao.Id];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Ocorreu um erro ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return anexos;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void cancelarSolicitacao(String solicitacao_id) {

        Id RecTypeId = RecordTypeMemory.getRecType('Case', 'Ajuda_Residencia_Alteracao_Contrato');
        Case minhaSolicitacao = new Case();
        try {
            minhaSolicitacao = [SELECT Id, Nova_Data_Inicio_Contrato__c, Data_Vigencia_Mudanca__c, Nova_Data_Termino_Contrato__c, Novo_Valor_Aluguel__c, Tipo_Solicitacao__c, Inicio_Beneficio__c, DataAbertura__c, Data_Inicio_Contrato__c, Data_Termino_Contrato__c, Numero_Solicitacao__c, OwnerId, Status, Valor_Aluguel__c, Previsao_Encerramento__c FROM Case WHERE Numero_Solicitacao__c = :solicitacao_id];
            system.debug('minhaSolicitacao>>>>> ' + minhaSolicitacao);
            **if (minhaSolicitacao == null) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('Registro não encontrado');**
            } else {

                PeopleSoft_0283_REQUEST.Request cancelarSolicitacao = new PeopleSoft_0283_REQUEST.Request();
                cancelarSolicitacao.CANCELAMENTO_SS_INSTALACAO = new PeopleSoft_0283_REQUEST.CANCELAMENTO_SS_INSTALACAO();
                cancelarSolicitacao.CANCELAMENTO_SS_INSTALACAO.id_solicitacao = solicitacao_id;

                PeopleSoft_0283_RESPONSE.Response response = PeopleSoft_0283_REQUEST.sendRequest(cancelarSolicitacao);

                if (response.Dados.codigo_retorno != '99') {
                    if (response.Dados.codigo_retorno == '01') {
                        throw new AuraHandledException('Registro não encontrado no sistema PeopleSoft');
                    } else {

                        minhaSolicitacao.Status = 'Cancelado';
                        update minhaSolicitacao;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Registro não encontado Alterar contrato Catch ' + e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException('Registro não encontado');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That particular line will never be executed because the query two lines above will not return `null` if no records are found. Instead, it'll throw an exception itself. See [Using SOQL Queries That Return One Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_single_row.htm).

You can handle this by catching the exception yourself and re-raising. The pattern would look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
try {
    Case minhaSolicitacao = [SELECT (fields) FROM Case WHERE Numero_Solicitacao__c = :solicitacao_id];
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AuraHandledException('Registro não encontrado');
}
```

You can test the exception handler because you control the data in the test environment. Running a test without creating data that matches the query will result in the exception being thrown, which you can catch and assert on in your test method.

Comment: Have I to declared solicitacao_id?
This showing the error follow. 
Variable does not exist: solicitacao_id

Comment: I just copied and pasted your query. The code in my answer is meant to illustrate the pattern; I deliberately omitted the field list, for example.

Comment: Ok! But, will be can to cover the line. You it would have form other for to cover  this line?

Comment: Sorry, @ThiagoS, I don't have time to do one-on-one assistance.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have other form for to resolved this line. 
if (minhaSolicitacao == null) { throw new AuraHandledException?

Comment: Hello! I don't got to cover this line **if (minhaSolicitacao == null) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('Registro não encontrado');** Can you help me?

Comment: Thiago, as I say above, you cannot cover that line because it will never be executed. `minhaSolicitacao` will never be `null`. You need to catch and handle a QueryException instead, everywhere you use this type of code.